# <No main classes found>

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

Followed an oracle tutorial on creating a GUI, the tutorial promised that upon running the application I will have to select the main class, however, Netbeans doesn't find any Main classes?

Here is my code:

```
public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {



/**
 * Creates new form GUI
 */
public GUI() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Bookshop");

    jTextField1.setText("Enter Title");
    jTextField1.setName(""); // NOI18N
    jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setText("Book Title");

    jButton1.setText("Submit");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 82, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap(244, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 18, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addGap(228, 228, 228))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:

     //Parse degrees Celsius as a double and convert to Fahrenheit.
String Title = (String)(jTextField1.getText());
jLabel1.setText("Selected Title:" + Title);

}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new GUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

I thought that "public static void main(String args[]) {" declared a main class. The class GUI.java is in the source package so I really don't understand.

Please note I'm very new to Java, and really appreciate your time.

Comment: Can you share link to this tutorial?

Comment: Your code works, maybe your error is caused by wrong use of netbeans?

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is correct, and I can't see anything obviously wrong with your main class.

Although having said that:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
```

should be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

If you right click on the Java file in your project window and select "run this file" or "debug this file" that will tell netbeans to execute that file ignoring the project settings.

If that works then go in the properties of your project and set the main class in there for future use.

Your best bet to track this down will be divide an conquer. Create a new file, create an empty `main()`method in it that just prints "hello world", then transfer your code across a section at a time until you find the thing that breaks it.

Comment: "Could not find or load main class GUI" - Don't worry I guess I'll start again with a new project.

Comment: I did just spot something, see edited answer. I don't think that will make a difference though.

Comment: @TimB either one works of those `main`s work, its just the first is better practice

Comment: Why "should be" in main declaration, there is no difference, or is just `code style`?

Comment: It's code style, although actually I was surprised that the args[] one worked at all since I see that layout so rarely.

Comment: It's just like an normal array declaration, `int array[]` will work fine, but `int[] array` is preferred. though `int array[]` is preferred by those accustomed to C

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on your Project in the project explorer
2. Click on properties
3. Click on Run
4. Make sure your Main Class is the one you want to be the entry point. (Make sure to use the fully qualified name i.e. mypackage.MyClass)
5. Click OK.
6. Right-click on your project; click 'Clean and Build`
7. Run Project

If you just want to run the file, right click on the class from the package explorer, and click Run File, or (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>), or (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>)

The mistake I've made before is when I create a new Project, I forget to unclick the "Create Main Class` check box and so it create a Class for me, which I don't like so I delete the class. In this case, I would have to do the above steps to fix the problem so it will run correctly. The Main class NetBeans creates for you, is the launching class. If you delete it, you need to manually specify the new launching class for the project, then clean and build.

Comment: Could not find or load main class GUI

Comment: Did you do all these steps?

Comment: Yes, followed it line by line.

Comment: Try clean an build after you do it. Then try and run. Right click on your project - click clean and build